# How to display a record in a treemap in a text area?

Tags: java, treemap

I have a created a small program with 2 text fields 2 buttons and a text area to display a record.

I have used a treemap to store records from text fields (I have made them in to objects), the problem is I am unable to display the saved records in the treemap on to the text area.
Even though I have used the `toString()` method, it doesn't print the record it just prints a memory value like this `"javaapplication18.names@181e7fe"` in the text area.

Here is what I have done :

```
String z=txtsearch.getText();      

private void btnsearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

   String z=txtsearch.getText();

   txtarea.setText(naturalOrderMap.get(z).toString());
   System.out.println(naturalOrderMap.get(z));

}           

private void txtgetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
   String k=txtname.getText();
   String p=txtid.getText();

   names put=new names(k,p); //this is a constructor from another class.
   naturalOrderMap.put(p,put);
}
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Object#toString` representation of `names` is being displayed. Either override `toString` in the `names` class to display the necessary fields or use getters to extract field information to be displayed.